# Fix Sagging Garage Beam

Tags: repair, ceiling, beam, support, sagging

I have a 1970 built 24x24 workshop with a recessed support beam that is perpendicular to 2x6 24in on center ceiling joists. The support beam is 24 feet long and is built with 2x10's bolted together with 1/2 plywood in-between. This beam has a 3-inch sag in it and is even noticeable from outside the garage.

[image: Workshop Attic]
[image: Beam Side]
[image: Beam Bottom]

Would the beam need to be replaced or could the existing beam be raised and supported?

If it could be raised and supported would building a load bearing wall perpendicular to the beam through the center of garage be enough to support the beam?

Comment: 2x10s beams might get away without a support post at 14 feet, 10 or 12 feet is better.  24 feet and sag is expected.  Usually to raise, you want to go slow, about a 1/4 inch every few days at the fastest.  Maybe a bit faster for an unfinished garage.  Two support posts should be enough once it is raised up, or a wall if you want.

Comment: From your pictures, there shouldn't be much load on the beam, except for the cantilevered moment of the joists.  The roof is supported by the walls with a standard ridge board at the top, so little or no roof load.  And you don't appear to have a lot of stuff stored above the joists.  It may be that your built-up beam isn't acting as a single wood member, but rather as 4 separate 2x10's loosely tied together.

Comment: And can you tell us how the 4 2x10's are fastened together?  I just see some bolted connections.  Usually there's a recommended nailing schedule (size of nails, spacing, etc) for building a beam like that.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The outside boards are just 2x2's running the length of the beam and seem to be support for the notched ceiling joists. In the second picture you can kind of see what I am trying to describe, but I'll get a better picture added. The 2x10' are secured together by bolts ever 30 inches.  Both sides seem to be peppered with nails on both sides of the beam and I not really sure the nail size used.

Comment: I get it.  So the beam itself only 2-2x10's, with plywood between them?  If so then 24' is way too long a span, with no supports along the way.